# frictionless planar pendulum with pivot on a rotating disk

Tags: dynamical-systems, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to find the system of equations describing a frictionless planar pendulum (of known mass and length) that has it's pivot point fixed to the edge of a rotating disk (angular speed $\omega$). The pivot's position on the disk edge is such that the pendulum swings in a plane tangent to the disk.

I interpretted the motion of the pendulum to be:

As the disk rotates, the pendulum moves with the disk's rotation and it moves in a plane perpendicular to the disk's motion.  So if you look at the disk from above, you'd see the pendulum spinning around the disk's edge, but also it'd be moving up and down, relatively, so that you'd see it pop up into the disk's plane, then drop down to be perpendicular to the disk.

[image]

I can't figure out where to start. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) Not sure if this would be better here or on the Physics site.
2) Can you clarify this? Is the plane that the pendulum swings in constant and the same as the plane that the disk rotates in? Or is the plane that the pendulum swings in perpendicular to the plane of the disk, so that it moves as the disk rotates?

Comment: @MattDickau I edited my question to clarify the motion of the pendulum, as I interpretted it.  I didn't put this in physics since the goal is to come up with the system, then analyze it equilibrium points, etc.

Comment: I could hardly imagine what you mean! Can you add some picture or something?

Comment: @H.R. I added a picture for further clarification.

Comment: what are the constraints for the motion of swinging pendulum? Is it allowed to move in any direction?

Comment: @H.R.  I put up a better image.  I believe the pendulum only moves along the indicated line.

Comment: Now, It is clear what you mean! :) I will think about it and let you know. I think the main thing here is doing the second Newton law in a moving frame. :)